# Fetch Data into Excel from batch file using vbs script

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file that run set of SQL queries and loads data into a table.

I have written VBA script for button click in excel to retrieve the data from the above table.

However now my requirement has changed to populate data into excel without button click. Also I do not want my code in workbook open event.

I have to change my vba code to .vbs script so that I can call it from batch file.
Please help me. Correct me if I am wrong with my approach.

Comment: Why don't you use an Excel Data Table instead: http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/11/04/excel-2007-getting-external-data.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Write a VBscript that:

Executes the bat

```
shell.Run """C:\...\my.bat"""
```

Then executes the macro (example below)

```
    RunMacro
     Sub RunMacro()
     Dim xl
     Dim xlBook      
     Dim sCurPath
     path = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
     Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
     Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(path & "\Workbook.xlsm", 0, True)      
     xl.Application.Visible = False
     xl.DisplayAlerts = False    
     xl.Application.run "Workbook.xlsm!Module.RunMacro"
     xl.ActiveWindow.close
     xl.Quit

     Set xlBook = Nothing
     Set xl = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: My excel is not getting updated with data.
However the macro is running correctly. 
I called the vbs from bat file.

Comment: You need to add a line to save the Excel file -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx The code above just executes the macro

Comment: I saved my excel file as .xlsm and everytime I open it, i have to enable the content. Is this the issue when opening the file through script also?

Comment: Try SaveAs instead and maybe increase the Trust level so the warning (enable macros) should not appear - not sure about this one but worth a try to make sure.

Comment: Did saveas work or did you have to change the trust level too?

Comment: I mentioned the full path of the file. that worked. thanks for your help.